# What are the minimum system requirements for animation and rendering in 3DS Max?

Tags: cpu, rendering, 3ds-max

I am learning 3DS Max and I think I need to do lot of animation and rendering.

I wanted to know how much (minimum) RAM and what CPU I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [3DS Max homepage](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/system-requirements/):

- **Intel® Pentium® 4 1.4 GHz** or equivalent AMD® processor with SSE2 technology
- **2 GB RAM** (4 GB recommended)
- 2 GB swap space (4 GB recommended)
- 3 GB free hard drive space
- Direct3D® 10 technology, Direct3D 9, or OpenGL-capable graphics card (256 MB or higher video card memory, 1 GB or higher recommended)

And the usual stuff:

- Three-button mouse with mouse driver software
- DVD-ROM drive
- Microsoft® Internet Explorer® 8.0 internet browser or higher or Mozilla® Firefox® 3.0 -internet browser or higher
- Internet connection for web downloads and Autodesk® Subscription-aware access

So to sum it up, every machine from the last ten years or so should be able to handle it. 3DS Max therefore seems to scale quite well. If you have a small budget (i.e. for a normal office PC), you shouldn't run into problems **at all**, although the performance might not be the best. If you can spend some more, you'll absolutely be fine running the software.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, as the OP wanted the configuration of the person, not the system ;p.

Comment: @Journeyman Dang, how could I forget this! :D

Comment: I'd add tho, as i was going to in my answer (which is identical to yours other than that) ,  that the specification listed, is fairly close to the average system from close to a decade ago, other than the ram, and the video card. nearly any modern system, even laptops should be able to handle this

Comment: @Journeyman True that - I put it in there. Thanks for the addition.

Comment: @all thanks guys , one thing is confusing me that suppose i want to make a complete 3d village with many building . can i still do that with same config. i mean there will be many small objects . how will max handle that

Comment: @Moorage Note that these requirements are set very very low. Today you almost can't buy a computer without at least a dualcore CPU, 4 GB RAM and a dedicated graphics card. I think you'll be fine!

Comment: @slhck I have IBM ThinkPad Laptop W510 core i7 Q720  , 8GB RAM , SSD. WIll that be sufficient for complete 3d village rendering

Comment: @Moorage Uhm, yep, that sounds like a very decent machine for a laptop.

Comment: @slhck actually someone made a 3d castle in max and he wrote in comment that it took 40 hours for him to render that . i was worried if i need to make a village with many castles , how long it will take

Comment: @Moorage I can't be too specific on this one, but the i7 is quite a workhorse. Rendering always takes time. What are your other options anyway? Do you want to buy a new PC?

Comment: @slhck no really , i don't want to but i am just curious to know what sort of PC they use for making movies , do they use super computers???

Comment: @Moorage They use clusters of many machines dedicated to just rendering (this is called [computer clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster)). Each machine just renders a part, but this reduces rendering time significantly. The same can be used for video projects too (for example in Apple Final Cut).

Comment: @slhck that was cool , thats why i was thinking they can't have 50GB RAM PC